# Bit Stuffing in Computer Networking

Tags: network-protocols

I am a little confuse about Bit Stuffing in Computer Networking. 
If our flag is "01111110". and Data is "0101111111111101110"(eleven consecutive 1) .What should be the output after bit stuffing?

Is it "01011111[**0**]11111[**0**]10110" or "01011111[**0**]1111110110"?

*[**0**] represents 0 added for bit stuffing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit stuffing is just inserting a 0 after five sequential 1s in the transmitted data. Flag `01111110` is just used as a marker for the beginning and end of the frame. As you could see, bit stuffing ensures that flag pattern can never occur in normal data.

So for data output after bit stuffing should be as follows (your first variant):

```
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 | 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 [0] 1 1 1 1 1 [0] 1 0 1 1 0| 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
     flag               \_______/     \_______/                    flag
                       5 seq. 1's      5 seq. 1's
```

*[0] represents 0 added for bit stuffing.

Comment: @Indranil If you find this answer correct accept it.